# How can I specify all typescript files inside a folder as a source for grunt?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, typescript

I am trying to run this gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        typescript: {
            base: {
                src: ['/app/*.ts'],
                dest: 'wwwroot/app.js',
                options: {
                    module: 'amd',
                    target: 'es5'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-typescript");
};
```

This works for files in /app/*.ts but how can I make it so that every .ts file (including those in subdirectories under /app) is run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
src: ['/app/**/*.ts'],
```